# How can I make an inline plot in Jupyter from F# interactive?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, f#, f#-interactive

I was able to generate a chart from F# interactive. However, the chart shows in the browser. I would like to see it show in an output cell. Is that possible?

I am using the Polyglot notebook extension.

I was able to generate a chart from F# interactive using this code:

```
#r "nuget: XPlot.Plotly"
#r "nuget: XPlot.Plotly.Interactive"

open XPlot.Plotly

let z = 3
let x = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
let y = [1; 4; 9; 16; 25]
printfn $"z = {z}"

let scatter = Scattergl(x = x, y = y, mode = "markers")

Chart.Plot([scatter])
|> Chart.WithTitle("Scatter Plot")
|> Chart.WithXTitle("X-Axis")
|> Chart.WithYTitle("Y-Axis")
|> Chart.Show
```

Comment: Are you using VS Code?

Comment: @BrianBerns Yes, I am using VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the cell to return the final chart, rather than call `Chart.Show`. This can be done by simply removing the final line:

```ml
Chart.Plot([scatter])
|> Chart.WithTitle("Scatter Plot")
|> Chart.WithXTitle("X-Axis")
|> Chart.WithYTitle("Y-Axis")
```

In VS Code, I've confirmed that this displays the chart in the notebook:

[image]